# How to blink LEDs with different frequency?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, microchip, timer

I have a pic32mx and three LEDs.
[datasheet pic32mx] (http://hades.mech.northwestern.edu/images/2/21/61132B_PIC32ReferenceManual.pdf)

I need a function that gets the number of LEDs and frequency, and then blinking the LED with that frequency.

For example I need to blink 1, 2, 4 and 8 times per second.
I have some code, but I don't know how to make it blink with the given frequency. Can somebody explain?

```
void main() {
T2CON = 0x0;                     // Stop and clean Control Register
T2CONSET = 0x0070;       // 16 bit timer, prescaler at 1:256,  internal clock source
PMR = 0x0;                        // Clean Timer Register
PR2 = 0xFFFF;                    //  Load value
IPC2SET = 0x0000000C;  // Set priority level=3
IPC2SET = 0x00000001;  //  Set subpriority level=1
IFS0CLR = 0x00000100;  // Clear the Timer2 interrupt status flag
IEC0SET = 0x00000100;  // Enable Timer2 interrupts
T2CONSET = 0x8000;      // START TIMER2
}

void __ISR(8,ipl3) TimerHandler {

//somecode

IFS0CLR = 0x00000100;
}
```

Comment: What do you think the supplied code does? How frequently does the penultimate line get executed?

Comment: This code initialization timer, i do this becuse i know that it can do whith timer and interrupts... @Spehro Pefhany

Comment: If you know the frequency of the interrupt, just use various global variable counters to count how many times the ISR has fired. When it hits your desired time, toggle the LED and reset the counter. For example, a 1ms ISR can have a counter to 250 for 1/4 of a second, and 1000 for a full second.

Comment: ok, but how to calculate and get value of frequency? @Kurt E. Clothier

Answer (score 3):

Lets say your led's connected to `RD0` `RD1` & `RD2`. First you need a exact 1sec delay. Following function will provide you 1sec delay

```
void Delayms( unsigned t)
{
  T1CON = 0x8000; 
  while (t--)
  { 
    TMR1 = 0;
    while (TMR1 < FPB/1000);
  }
}
```

Now you said that blink led for 1,2,4 or 8 times per second.That means to blink led 1 times per second means half of the 1sec, led will be on and half of 1sec led will be off, which you can do it like this:

```
int main()
{
  TRISD = 0; //making all led's output
  while(1)
  {
    PORTD = 1; //led's will be on
    Delayms(500) //led's will be on for 500ms
    PORTD = 0;//led's will be off
    Delayms(500); //led's will be off for 500ms
  }
}
```

Now blinking led's 2 times per second means led will be on for 250ms then led off for 250ms and again the same thing. You can do it by replacing the delay by 250ms.
So in this way you can blink led's for 4 or 8 times per second.

Answer (score 2):

I won't provide actual code because I'm not familiar with the PIC though I have done a lot of embedded programming with other processors.

In order to flash a LED 8 times a second you need to change its state 16 times a second.

So you first generate an interrupt that fires 16 times a second.

Each time you go around this loop toggle the state of this LED.

To flash a LED 4 times a second you toggle its state half as often so not every time the interrupt fires but every other time.

Similarly the LED flashing twice a second is toggled every 4th interrupt and the LED flashing once a second every 8th interrupt.

---

I have not tried this but you first set your timer to run with a \$ \frac{1}{16} \$ second tick as described in section 14 of the reference manual you linked to then generate interrupts from that.  It looks like you have not calculated the time for the period register PR2.

Comment: I dont know how to write a function that get number of LED and frequency that it blink with the given frequency, because i initialization timer only at once.for example 80MHz:256:65535 @Warren Hill

Comment: As I said I am not familiar with PIC processors but the user manual for your particular processor should tell you how to configure a timer based interrupt. If you are still struggling it might be an idea to edit your question to tell us which PIC you are using and links to its data sheet and user manual.

Comment: [datasheet](http://hades.mech.northwestern.edu/images/2/21/61132B_PIC32ReferenceManual.pdf)  pic32mx @Warren Hill

Answer (score 1):

Increment a counter variable 16 time a second (either by interrupt or in a loop with delay, whatever is more appropriate for you).

Output `bit0-3` of the counter.

`bit0` will blink with 8 Hz.
`bit1` will blink with 4 Hz.
`bit2` will blink with 2 Hz.
`bit3` will blink with 1 Hz.